# Using CloudWatch API to get statistics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have deployed a LAMP stack application on AWS. I need to monitor that using CloudWatch.

Can someone guide me on how to use the CloudWatch API for GetMetrics for CPU utilization? The [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cloudwatch/) is very scarce.

I see that the putmetrics call will let me create my own metrics. 
My requirement is that I need to display those metric results in a mobile app.
My app monitors a project deployed on AWS. The alerts and metrics that come in must stream into the app. 
I don't want just the metrics data in the AWS console, 
I want it viewable in my mobile app. The app is developed in MEAN stack. 
I must also add that the app is deployed on AWS and the application that is 
being monitored is also in there(its a LAMP stack). I have managed to set 2 endpoints(HTTP and DB) and I have written 
simple scripts in Javascript to monitor them. But ideally they should happen via Cloudwatch.

Comment: I have made some tiny progress i think..but i get this error "Could not find operation GetMetricStatistics  for version 2010-08-01" when i give the metric as cpu utilization with the dimension name as InstanceId and the value as the instance's value.  i have checked all the places in the code that has the version and the version is 2010 but i still get this eror!

Comment: somebody please help...i dont see any helpful information about this error on the internet

Comment: Ok...i checked the same thing on the AWS CLI and it worked...but it wont work for me in my application!

Answer (score 0):

Providing a piece of code that replicates the issue that you are seeing normally allows who sees the question to help you better than guessing what you're doing.

Are you using an SDK to do this? What language/version?

here are links to the API docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_ListMetrics.html

The pattern is to list the metrics and after that use the result and feed it into getmetricsstatistics.

In your specific case, googling the issue a bit before might answer the question before you ask it on SO. For example:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=295740

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you are hitting the wrong endpoint. Check if you are hitting endpoint of the right AWS service.

For example, trying to hit DynamoDB's endpoint when you want to access CloudWatch APIs.